# Excel VBA - Unprotect worksheet on cell selection (single click, NOT double-clicking)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro in Excel 2010 that will unprotect my worksheet when clicking **(not double-clicking)** a cell in a specific range, at the contrary, if I click anywhere else, I'd like to protect my worksheet.

Sorry, I'm not a VBA expert.

I came up with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E9:E22,I9:I21,N9:N20,Q9:Q14")) Is Nothing Then

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"

    ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range("E9:E22,I9:I21,N9:N20,Q9:Q14")) Is Nothing Then

        ActiveSheet.Protect _
        Password:="abc", _
        UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowSorting:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

    End If
End Sub
```

This code is perfectly working if, obviously, I double-click the cell, but I was wondering if there is any way to make it works if I only select (one click) a cell?

I tried using `ActiveCell` instead of `Target` but with no success.

Thank you very much,
Stefano

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: There's no `BeforeSingleClick` event, so if you're ok with `SelectionChange` - it's your choice. If you need only click - there's option to trap `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` via API. So it's better to be ok with first option.

Comment: Thanks Scott and thanks CommonSense, `SelectionChange` works perfectly well for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to you are using `BeforeDoubleClick` Event.
Try using `Worksheet_SelectionChange` instead.